# LogicApp: Send an email action with office365 outlook after trigger after trigger on new emails cannot send attached msg-files. How can I avoid it?

Tags: email, attachment, azure-logic-apps

if i will attach an msg-file to an email or drag a outlook mail as attachment in a new mail and send it, oin the logic app it will appear like a forwarded message only normal attachements from the attached e-mail will attached to the new email the body of attached emails will included inth new mail body.

Is there an way only without logic apps on receiveing such a mail to send an new e-mail with the attachement as the the sender did it.
Or could i prevent the embedding of mail-attachments so that it will be attached as normal file-attachement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my infos, it is not possible msg files will be mebedded in the body automatically. With logic apps  direct it is only possible to send attached mails as eml-files not  msg-files.

I think it is only possible to write an azure function and call it from logic app or use graph api to send the e-mail with msg attachment (not tested).

```
[https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http][1]
```

Comment: in 5 days  I will set it as solved as no one will correct it or extend it or say that is wrong.